# I add a "align" constraint, but Xcode add a "pin" constraint autolayout

Tags: xcode6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

When we add constraints, we have the choice between "Align" button in the auto layout toolbar or "Pin" button.

In my storyboard, if I add a new alignment constraint "Bottom edges" between a scrollview and his container.

[image: Align]

The icon of this constraint is 2 squares and a line.

But after, in the list of constraints of my scrollview, the icon is different :

[image: Pin]

The icon is a "Pin" icon.

I don't understand why.

One more question, I think it's related : what is the difference between "Align bottom" and "Bottom space" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pin** and **Align** are just abstractions to make it easier to understand what you are setting up.  In reality, a constraint is a relation between attributes of two objects.  What you specify in Interface Builder with align or pin gets translated into an `NSLayoutConstraint` object.

When done programmatically, there is no **pin** or **align** option, you are just specifying the objects, their attributes (`.Top`, `.Bottom`, `.CenterX`, etc.) , the relation (`.Equal`, `.GreaterThanOrEqual`, `.LessThanOrEqual`), a constant, and a multiplier.

For example, here is how to align the bottoms of two buttons:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button2, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

If the two objects are siblings, then their bottoms are considered to be **aligned**.  If one object is a subview of the other object, then it is considered to be **Bottom Space**.  Both are just a relation between the `.Bottom` of one view to the `.Bottom` of the other view.

When you click on the constraint and view it in the Attributes Inspector, you see the values that are used to create the `NSLayoutConstraint`.

[image: Align button bottoms]