# Difference between pin and align in autolayout?

Tags: ios, xcode6, storyboard, autolayout

What is the difference between align and pin attributes in auto layout in storyboard?

Comment: this link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27893049/5362916

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I add a "align" constraint, but Xcode add a "pin" constraint autolayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892626/i-add-a-align-constraint-but-xcode-add-a-pin-constraint-autolayout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pin Tool:**

- Pin tool lists positioning and size attributes (described in About Auto Layout and Layout Constraints).These attributes refer to the selected items’ alignment rectangles. Only valid constraint options are enabled.
- Pin tool to see the different types of constraints that you can put in place. Width/height constraints enforce a given width or height on an object. Equal width/height constraints ensure multiple objects maintain an equal width or height. The leading/trailing space pinnings tie the left side of an object to the left side of its parent view (leading), or the right side of an object to the right side of its parent view (trailing).
- Pin tool, we **can select single item** and then set constraints to its nearest neighbour(which may be containing superview a nearby)

Example :

[image]

**Align tool:**

- Align tool  for aligning multiple objects as well as for aligning a single object with the horizontal or vertical center (or both) of a container.
- Align tool lets us **select two or more elements** and then set constraints to align their edges,centres and resizing behaviour

Example:

[image]

for more information: [Auto Layout Constraints with the Pin and Align Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014226-CH28-SW1)